# sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed, html

Using `sed` I need to replace variables in an HTML document.

The following is what i am using:

```
cat $email_temp\
 | sed 's/\$message_entry/Flex File Export completed successfully for'"$run_date"'./g'\
 | sed 's/\$run_date/'"$run_date"'/g'\
 | sed 's/\$flex_file_new_count/\'"$flex_file_new_count"'/g'\
 | sed 's/\$exported_file_count/'"$exported_file_count"'/g'\
 | sed 's/\$date_data/\'"$date_data"'/g'\
 | sed 's/\$flex_file_old_count_data/\'"$flex_file_old_count_data"'/g' > $email_body
```

Comment: It's hard to say what you're doing wrong when we don't know what you're trying to do.  Please edit your question and describe what you're trying to do, and how what you've tried behaved differently than what you want.

Comment: You have mismatch because of `'` character.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: Does run date include any slashes?

Comment: hi @Mikel date format is 2019-11-03

Comment: "...and how what you've tried behaved differently than what you want."

Comment: Whenever you inject stuff externally u need to vet them carefully. Check if your variable is having newlines. Especially $flex_file_new_count.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by [@unxnut](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550214/sed-e-expression-1-char-24-unterminated-s-command#comment1021287_550214), there are three escaped single quotes `\'` in your command which should not be escaped. 
Thus `sed` cannot find the matching closing single quote and fails.

Try this (with quoted variables `$email_temp`, `$email_body` and one `sed` call):

```
sed -e 's/\$message_entry/Flex File Export completed successfully for'"$run_date"'./g'\
 -e 's/\$run_date/'"$run_date"'/g'\
 -e 's/\$flex_file_new_count/'"$flex_file_new_count"'/g'\
 -e 's/\$exported_file_count/'"$exported_file_count"'/g'\
 -e 's/\$date_data/'"$date_data"'/g'\
 -e 's/\$flex_file_old_count_data/'"$flex_file_old_count_data"'/g' "$email_temp" > "$email_body"
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn't work for me ... i am still getting error sed: -e expression #3, char 24: unterminated `s' command